# How to get the value of max length in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, maxlength

i would like to ask you if there is a way to get the value of maxlength of column in ms sql server.
For example in the table A we have:

```
id  | value
----+--------
 1  | 0123
 2  | 00034567
 3  | 547
```

The desired result for this data set is 00034567.

Wherever i have searched for this problem i get the answer select max(len(value)) which is not what i need, because it gives the max number of characters of the value and not the value itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.value
FROM table AS t
ORDER BY LEN(t.value) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It gives the correct result!!

Answer (score 1):

Sort by length and take the first row:

```
select top 1 value
from mytable
order by len(value) desc
```

If you want ties:

```
select value
from mytable
where len(value) = (select max(len(value)) from mytable)
```

Or more efficient but SQL Server specific:

```
select value from (
  select value,
  rank() over (order by len(value) desc) rank
  from mytable) x
where rank = 1
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3ddc/4) for last one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You aggree with the first answer i got and you are also correct

Answer (score 0):

the sql you use is correct, u just have to cast it to an nvarchar

Comment: well isnt that what you want? if you suggest that what you need is 34567 > than 547 then, as it is an integer with just select MAX() would suffice.

Comment: yes you are right if the field has only integers, but this is not my case unfortunately. Thanks a lot for your time. My question has been answered. Please see above.